# How to read a text file into a string in one line of code

Tags: javascript

With all of the updates to JavaScript in the last few years, is there a way to read a text file into a string with one line of code?

Something like:

```
var data = await fetch(url).data;
```

Comment: `await (await fetch(url)).text()`?

Comment: Are we talking a local file, or a text file served by a web server?

Comment: @BrettDonald served from a webserver

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `response.text()` to get the contents returned from `fetch()`.

```
let data = await fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean "local file" because you mentioned "file" and "read".

It has always been one line excluding import.

```js
import { readFile } = require('fs/promises');
const data = await readFile("path/to/file.txt", "utf8");
```